# How to show values in pop up to a parent web form Grid View?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, popup

I have a pop up that displays **User's Account Title, Balance and creation date** after intake of User's Account and Pin Number ...

i want to show these three values at my parent web form Grid view at which the pop up was linked. ...

**How can i do that ... How can i show the three values in gridview?**

I have binded the Grid view with an object MergeAccount with the following method:

```
 public DataSet ShowDetails(int acc,int pin)
{
    this.AccountNumber = acc;
    this.PinNumber = pin;
    SqlConnection con = DALBankAccount.connect;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Title,CreationDate,Balance from AccountsDetails where AccountNo='" + AccountNumber + "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();
    MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet, "AccDetails");
    return MyDataSet;
}
```

The user should have a final display of all the accounts he have merged in a gridview of parent web form after he have Closed the pop up ..

Comment: Before showing the PopUp, query the "User's Account Title, Balance and creation date" inthe Parent Form & then post these values to the PopUp. Do not query the value in the PopUp itself.

Comment: if i have done that in pop .. aint there any way to display it at parent web form's Grid view .. Because since the user will have to merge accounts he would make use of pop up to retreive his account information more then once of course! ...

Comment: Its not that you cannot do that. Anyways pop-up is a modal dialog and until user closes it he won't be able to access the parent form. My question is - What are you achieving by querying in the pop up because the pop-up is being launched by that form where you want to show the value itself. And, I am sure that as soon as the PopUp is displayed, you are trying to fill the grid or whatever.

Comment: Pop up is helping User to see if he is entering a valid account information or not .. if not , Pop up prompts user to enter correct stuff else it displays the Account details in Pop up only

Answer (score 0):

You may refer these links please -

1. [Sending data between an asp.net page and a pop up page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397864/sending-data-between-an-asp-net-page-and-a-pop-up-page)
2. http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/282/passing-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-form39s-textbox/rev/1

Hope this solves your issue.